# Would having only 3 fingers/toes on their hands/feet affect a humanoid species negatively?

Tags: biology, creature-design, anatomy, humanoid

So I have this 3-2 1/2 feet tall humanoid species called Pinokiins that as of the time of typing have 3 fingers(thumb included) and toes on their hands and feet instead of 5. Is this a negative thing? Could they still have as much dexterity as humans? Could they play the same instruments as we do and as good? Could they make detailed drawings and paintings like us? Could they still have the same grip as us? They tend to go on all 4s when they run or travel long distances on foot as they have arms as long as their legs and are hunched over alot, so would having 12 digits in-all instead of 20 make this difficult to do?

Comment: A hand for walking on is not going to be very good a grabbing, they require vert different shapes. That is going to have a much much bigger effect than the number of fingers.

Comment: @John Well their hands are human-like, minus 2 fingers.

Comment: If a human tried to habitually walk on their hands they would almost certainly end up dislocating a finger.

Comment: They would have extreme difficulty responding to a "High Five"

Comment: Probably just a more extreme case of those unfortunate people who only have 5 fingers left (per hand).  But I think what you find is that when people do have fewer digits (injury/amputation, birth defects, whatever) they tend to adapt as best as they can, often spectacularly/surprisingly well, but individual results vary.

Comment: Manicurists would make 3/5ths as much money.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding!  If you haven't already, do take a look at the [tour] and [help] and read through [What Worlduilding is All About](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about). You've got an interesting basis for at least a half dozen questions here, but you really need to focus on one single worldbuilding issue or problem at a time. Am voting to close your query so you can consider and edit it accordingly.

Comment: @John chimps walk on their hands (knuckle walking) yet they can grab stuff with more force than us.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw first chimps nuckle walk which is a big diffrence, second chimps have a strong grip and very little precision. human in general have a weak grip but a lot of precision and stamina.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Three fingers can produce all the [necessary grips](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-comprehensive-grasp-taxonomy-Feix-Pawlik/ff6edd2fde1d38a01294c974611355b34e99a0dd) the only one that really suffers is the clutch  grip, (AKA ball grip, AKA sphere grip, AKA ect. grip), but it still works it is just not as good, and almost half of the other possible hand grips only use three fingers anyway. A lot of the most important tasks (like stone knapping) depend more on the wrist than the fingers.

[image]

Grip strength depends on the muscles on the arm not the number of fingers, three fingers may actually end up being stronger since you can have thicker finger bones and tendons in the same area.

Answer (score 6):

A hand with three fingers is just about the minimum needed for the tasks humans use our hands for. I was once informed by a historical reenactor that early modern armies mandated that their soldiers have at least three functional digits per hand. (Recruiting standards back then were lower, to say the least.)

Tools, musical instruments, et cetera would need to be designed a bit differently to accommodate a non-human hand structure. Playing a harp, for example, or typing on a keyboard would be harder with fewer fingers.

If these creatures walk on their hands, they likely have a gorilla-like body plan.  Knuckle-walking evolved [multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalicotherium) [times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megatherium) in Earth's history, as it's the easiest way to have a foot that works both as a load-bearing element and a hand.

Comment: Could they do without the knuckle walking if they are lighter and smaller then most humans? They are only 3 foot tall at max, and weight just as much, if not less, then a 3 year old when full grown. @Karst

Comment: It might be doable, but curling up the hands when they walk on them would still help keep the palms/fingers from getting too calloused.

Comment: @ConanHighwoods it is unlikely they could do both effectively the problem is how far toe fingers have to flex, to walk on them effectively the fingers should be fairly stiff to prevent dislocation and a little flexed forward, while for grip fingers need to be flexible and with a wide range of movement. they literally require the exact opposite adaptations.